# API Changes: Affine2DOperationDeltaEventArgs equivalent in Surface 2.0

Tags: .net-4.0, pixelsense

I am porting the [SurfaceToTUIO](http://johannesluderschmidt.de/lang/de/microsoft-surface-tuio-overlay/895/) software from Surface 1.0 to 2.0 API. After fixing several errors I am stuck on the following error:

```
Error 1 The type or namespace name 'Affine2DOperationDeltaEventArgs' 
could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly 
reference?) App1.cs 82 33 SurfaceToTUIO
```

I was checking the API Changes in 2.0 but there are no references to the equivalent class.

The class belonged to Microsoft.Surface.Core.Manipulations namespace, that has been removed and integrated into [System.Windows.Input.Manipulations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.manipulations.aspx) namespace. However, it seems that the class has been disappeared or renamed.

Any help or ideas?

Many thanks in advance